# What is causing this garbage when writing to a file

Tags: python, unicode, encoding

I am trying to figure out what is happening in this situation. I am on Windows 7 64-bit and I was experimenting with Unicode in Python.

With the following Python code

```
#aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
#aaaaaa

x = [u'\xa3']

f = open('file_garbage.txt', 'w+')
for s in x:
    if s in f.read():
        continue
    else:
        f.write(s.encode('utf-8'))
f.close()
```

I get no error message and file_garbage.txt contains

```
£
```

when I add another item to x like so

```
#aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
#aaaaaa

x = [u'\xa3',
     u'\xa3']

f = open('file_garbage.txt', 'w+')
for s in x:
    if s in f.read():
        continue
    else:
        f.write(s.encode('utf-8'))
f.close()
```

I get a UnicodeDecodeError

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "file_garbage.py", line 9, in <module>
    if s in f.read():
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe0 in position 2: ordinal not in range(128)
```

file_garbage.txt will contain either around 250 lines of bytes like this

```
c2a3 4b02 e0a6 5400 6161 6161 6161 6161
6161 6161 6161 6161 6161 6161 6161 6161
6161 6161 6161 6161 6161 610d 0a23 6161
6161 6161 0d0a 0d0a 7820 3d20 5b75 275c
7861 3327 2c0d 0a20 2020 2020 7527 5c78
6133 275d 0d0a 0d0a 6620 3d20 6f70 656e
2827 6669 6c65 5f67 6172 6261 6765 2e74
```

garbage like in this

```
Â£Kà¦éaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
#aaaaaa

x = [u'\xa3',
     u'\xa3']

f = open('file_garbage.txt', 'w+')
for s in x:
    if s in f.read():
        continue
    else:
        f.write(s.encode('utf-8'))
f.close()
 Python Character Mapping Codec cp1252 generated from 'MAPPINGS/VENDORS/MICSFT/WINDOWS/CP1252.TXT' with gencodec.py.

iÿÿÿÿNt
```

followed by a bunch of ENQ, DC2, SOH, STX, NUL symbols and links to:

```
 C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp1252.py
```

Pic of garbage:

[image: garbage]

I am guessing that this is a problem to do with encoding and/or the way I am dealing with files, but I am confused about what is happening exactly and why the results seem to differ.

The garbage seems to only be generated if those seemingly random couple of comment strings at the top of the file but the bytes will always be generated otherwise.

If it helps, my system encodings are set as follows:

```
sys.stdout.encoding            :  cp850
sys.stdout.isatty()            :  True
locale.getpreferredencoding()  :  cp1252
sys.getfilesystemencoding()    :  mbcs
```

Comment: Are you trying to write to the same file that the code is running from?  Your examples look like you're saying the garbage is in `file_garbage.py`, but your code shows you opening something called `file_garbage.txt`.

Comment: No I am trying to write to a separate text file called `file_garbage.txt` from `file_garbage.py`, I just named both files file_garbage for testing, sorry for the confusion

Comment: So you are trying to write to `file_garbage.txt`, but `file_garbage.py` is actually being modified?

Comment: Try removing the `.encode('utf-8')`, you don't open the file as binary, so you should pass it a string not a bytearray and it will take care of the encoding.

Comment: @BrenBarn I tried changing the filename `file_garbage.txt` to something completely different but I still end up with the garbage in the new .txt file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible that the file is being corrupted because it is not closed properly.  I've never seen this particular behavior but it's within the realm of possibility.  Try changing your code to use `with`:

```
with open('file_garbage.txt', 'w+') as f:
    # do your stuff here
```

This will ensure that the file is closed even if an exception is raised.

The cause of the exception is that `x` contains unicode strings, but when you read in `f` you are reading in bytes.  When you try to check `s in f.read()`, it tries to compare the unicode string to the bytes in the file, and fails because the bytes in the file can't be interpreted as unicode.  You need to decode the contents of the file back into unicode.

Your code has a few other problems that are somewhat outside the scope of this question.  For starters, using `f.read()` in a loop like that won't work, because the first read will read the whole file, and subsequent reads will return nothing.  Instead, read (and decode) the file into a variable first, then do your comparison against that variable.  Also, I'm not sure if reading and writing the file in `w+` mode will do what you want.  (I'm not actually sure what you want your code to do.)  As [documented](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open), `w+` truncates the file, so you won't be able to "update" it by adding to what's already there.

Comment: Using `with` and storing the decoded `f.read()` in a variable then checking against the variable has indeed solved the issue. I was only using `w+` in this example temporarily to test the garbage output, previously I was using `a+` to read and append to the file. Thank you very much for clearing up my confusion.